# Object reference not set to an instance of an object, guess not added to List<Guess>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to c# MVC and I don't understand my error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

I have the following in my Controller:

```
namespace Prigmore2013_01.Tests
{
    public class Exercise09Controller : Controller
    {
       ...
        public ActionResult GuessTheDigits(List<int> guesses)
        {
            GuessingGame theGame = this.Session["GameState"] as GuessingGame;
            theGame.GuessTheHiddenDigits(guesses);
            // The above is passing to the method in GuessingGame class?

            return RedirectToAction("Index", theGame);

        }
        ...
    }
}
```

I am calling the `theGame.GuessTheHiddenDigits(guesses);` and passing this across to the following class:

```
namespace Prigmore2013_01.Models
{
    public class GuessingGame
    {
        public GuessingGame()
        {

            this.Guesses = new List<Guess>();
            this.Target = new List<int>();
            this.guess = new List<int>();

        }
        public List<int> Target { get; set; }
        public List<Guess> Guesses { get; set; }
        public List<int> guess { get; set; }

        public void GuessTheHiddenDigits(List<int> guesses)
        {
            // getting the guesses passed from the controller, debugging shows that
            this.guess = new List<int>(guesses);
            Guess m = new Guess();
            m.Digits.AddRange(this.guess);
        }
    }
}
```

I have another class called `Guess`:

```
namespace Prigmore2013_01.Models
{
    public class Guess
    {
        public Guess()
        {
            this.Digits = new List<int>();
        }

        public List<int> Digits { get; set; }

        public object RightDigitRightPosition { get; set; }

        public object RightDigitWrongPosition { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The above method `public void GuessTheHiddenDigits(List<int> guesses)` within here needs to add a submitted guess `(guesses)`  to the `List<Guess>` objects. I thought I had instantiated the method by doing this:

```
this.guess = new List<int>(guesses);
Guess m = new Guess();
m.Digits.AddRange(this.guess);
```

EDIT 1: 
Found the error that has formed within the Unit test that I am running:

```
[TestMethod]
        public void GuessTheHiddenDigitsAddsTheSubmittedGuessToTheListOfGuesses()
        {
            var theGame = new GuessingGame();
            /* NOTE : The next line forces us to add a behaviour to the GuessingGame
             * class: the GuessTheHiddenDigits() method.  
             * */
            theGame.GuessTheHiddenDigits(new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 });
            var theContext = new FakeHttpContext();
            var theKey = "GameState";
            theContext.Session.Add(theKey, theGame);
            var controller = new Exercise09Controller();
            var request = new System.Web.Routing.RequestContext(theContext, new System.Web.Routing.RouteData());
            controller.ControllerContext = new System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext(request, controller);
            //Finally, set up the new guess
            var theGuess = new List<int>() { 2, 3, 4 };

            //Act
            controller.GuessTheDigits(theGuess);
            var result = controller.ShowPreviousGuesses();
            var lastGuess = ((List<Guess>)result.Model).LastOrDefault();

            //Assert
            /* NOTE : This line forces another implementation decision: to use a
             * C# property for Guess.Digits to represent the player's guess.
             * */
            CollectionAssert.AreEqual(theGuess, lastGuess.Digits);
        }
```

**My Unit test breaks on the lastGuess.Digits as this is null. Does this mean I require a constructor initially to create a new list so that isn't null and will not throw the error?**

I seem to be going round in circles and don't quite understand what is causing this to not be set. Would it be possible for someone to explain to me why my method isn't adding to my `List<Guess>` and the best approach for adding my submitted guess to `List<Guess>`?

Comment: The error means that you're trying to dereference (use) a `null` value. Debug your code to find where the exception is being thrown, what's null, and why.

Comment: I have updated my code to include the Unit Test where the code breaks.

Answer (score 2):

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

means that you're using a variable which equals to `null`, I guess that following lines are problematic:

```
GuessingGame theGame = this.Session["GameState"] as GuessingGame;
theGame.GuessTheHiddenDigits(guesses);
```

So in this case `theGame` is probably not set, because you haven't saved it in `Session["GameState"]`, thus it throws an error because you're trying to call a method on `null`ed variable.

**UPDATE**

Since you already know where this error occurs, then you need to know that using a variable which has a `null` value will result in this kind of error, to prevent it you need to initialize your variables.

Comment: I have debugged my code to find that `theGame` isn't set to null and instead my unit test fails. I have updated my code to include my unit test to make things clearer.

Comment: Further to your update, would this be where a constructor is required to initially set the property to a new instance? or would a new instance override the data already contained within the property?

Comment: I'd expect this to be initialized via constructor.

Answer (score 0):

First off, use the debugger and when you get that error inspect your objects/properties to see which one is null.

> I seem to be going round in circles and don't quite understand what is
>   causing this to not be set. Would it be possible for someone to
>   explain to me why my method isn't adding to my List and the
>   best approach for adding my submitted guess to List?

In `GuessingGame.GuessTheHiddenDigits` method you are creating a local scope object of type Guess, and adding the passed in `List<int>` to that ... nowhere are you actually adding anything to your `GuessingGame.Guesses` list. That 'm' will be removed as soon as that method has finished executing.

Are you then intending to add 'm' to your List?

Like:

```
Guess m = new Guess();
m.Digits.AddRange(this.guess);
this.guess.Add(m);
```

Oh, and `this.guess` doesn't match naming rules for public properties ... call it `this.Guess` instead.

Comment: So because the 'm' is a local variable, that is why nothing will get set because as soon as the method has run that variable is lost? Would explain why when I step through, that I can see the property in my `Guess class` getting set but would explain why it fails. Further to my original question I have located that the `Guess.Digits` is not set which is causing the error. How, within my `GuessingGame.GuessTheHiddenDigits` would I set a property within another class?